# jQuery Lightbox single image display

Tags: jquery, gallery, lightbox

Is there a way to make lightbox only show the image clicked on and not show an entire gallery.
I am not interested in giving the user the ability to see other images aside from the one they clicked on, but the documentation doesn't seem to reflect this functionality.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
#lightbox-nav a {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that link, AlienWebguy. Is that a different lightbox? The one you're showing me uses prototype and scriptaculous versus the jquery version I'm using.

Comment: Ah I apologize, I didn't see you were using the JQuery version.

Comment: Outstanding! Just what the doctor ordered! I tried display: none; but not the important bit. Obviously that forces the case and that's what I was missing.  Thanks a million. :)

Comment: please note this method is a hack... it is still a gallery, you only hide navigation. better option is to init lightbox on the items separately then they each turn into their own gallery.

Answer (score -1):

you can hide the navigation as explained in another answer here
but a nice solution is to initialize the lightbox plugin on each item separately.

instead of `$('#gallery a').lightBox();`  you can do this:

```
$('#gallery a').each(function(){
    $(this).lightBox();
});
```

the gallery is actually made of each item that fits the selector,
if you select 10 items those will be your gallery, but if you launch `.lightBox()` on each separately, they each get added to their own gallery (convenientely the plugin hides the controls when only 1 items is in the gallery.)

see an example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/kwdBf/

Comment: If you have 50 images on a page, that's 50 instances of lightBox(). Yikes!

Comment: i would however need to see what the performance issue is here, without proof i still go for this instead of a css hack